# VSCodium - can't configure Python support

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, ide

I'm using VSCodium and I can't install any kind of Python support.

I have Python installed on my OS (`5.6.15-arch1-1`), available in `$PATH`.

When I follow the [guide](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python#quick-start) I can't install the plugin and get IntelliSense/whatever working.

[image: SS]

```
code --version
1.46.1
cd9ea6488829f560dc949a8b2fb789f3cdc05f5d
x64
```

How to install plugins in order to have Python3 support in this IDE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with Python extension like [Jill Cheng](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62769472/5709117) said, but couldn't install it due errors.

`code --install-extension ms-python.python`

It failed due weird error:

`Installing extensions...Cannot read property 'length' of null`

What I did:

1. Update vscodium (`yay -Sy vscodium-bin` in my case)
2. `sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.vscode-oss`
3. Suddenly it worked when installing from GUI again - previously nothing was happening

I assume update fixed something deep inside VSCodium, since `chown` didnt change any ownership in config folder.

Answer (score 0):

You could check that your VSCodium has successfully installed [Python extensions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/python#_install-python-and-the-python-extension).

I reproduced the problem you described, and after installing the python extension, the problem is solved.